# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Assign Identity User to custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Lets say i have model Post.cs and u want to add user who create this post.I think i can use Identity users directly and attach them to post, or maybe only their ID's. I don't want to extend it, just to assign it to the post. Here is my custom model:

```
 public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }
}
```

On the fourth and fifth row is the APS.NET default identity user data that i want to assign to posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your question exactly. If you are trying to create a one-to-many relationship, see this simple example.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }


}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

This will create a one-to-many relationship between User and Posts. Post has one User but User can have multiple Posts. With that you have also extended the IdentityUser.

Comment: Thats kinda correct answer i achieve what i want. Thank you.Onemore question. By this code above when i do some request to get all Posts with users who's created  them, my "UserId" field is filled with the id of the user in Identity service, but field "user" is null, should get it by reference from "UserId"?

Comment: Please read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data it explains the include method in EF.